# Radio button change event does not trigger for on Value change dynamically

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms, onchange, syncfusion

I am having a simple Angular Reactive form with Radio buttons. When I change the selected radio button value using formControl, the change event does not trigger. Is there any other event that triggers whenever the Radio button selection changed dynamically?
Also, I am trying to use Syncfusion `ejs-radiobutton`, but this doesn't seem to work on simple HTML input[type="radio"].

```js
export class App {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    option: new FormControl('option2'),
  });
  onChanged(e: any) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  submit() {
    this.form.controls.option.setValue('option3');
  }
}
```

```html
<ul [formGroup]="form" style="margin-top: 50px">
  <!--  <li>
    <ejs-radiobutton #radio label="Option 1" formControlName="option" name="option" [value]="'option1'"></ejs-radiobutton>
  </li>

  <li>
    <ejs-radiobutton label="Option 2" formControlName="option" name="option" [value]="'option2'"></ejs-radiobutton>
  </li>
-->

  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio"  formControlName="option" name="option" [value]="'option1'" (change)="onChanged($event)" />
                Option 1
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio"  formControlName="option" name="option" [value]="'option2'" (change)="onChanged($event)" />
                Option 2
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="radio"  formControlName="option" name="option" [value]="'option3'" (change)="onChanged($event)" />
                Option 3
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<button (click)="submit()">Click</button>
```

In the above code, I am trying to set the input value when the button is clicked. But, the change event is not triggered.

Comment: I just want to change the radio button formControlValue and whenever the radio button selection is changed, I want an event to trigger. change event doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to formControl.valueChanges (don't forget unsubscribe)

```
changes!:Subscription
ngOnInit()
{
     this.changes=this.form.controls.option.valueChanges
                                 .subscribe((res:string)=>{
                                       console.log("change",res)
                                  })
}
ngOnDestroy()
{
     this.changes.unsubscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, when using radio input types, the change event doesn't get triggered when the radio button value is changed. Similarly, the Syncfusion radio button doesn't trigger the event when its value is changed. As a result, users need to manually invoke the code that should execute when the event is triggered. Please refer to the below code snippet.

```
export class AppComponent {

form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({

    option: new FormControl('option2'),

  });

  onChanged(e: any) {

    this.change({name: e.name, value: e.value});

  }
  change(args: any) {

    console.log(args.value);

  }
  submit() {

    this.form.controls.option.setValue('option3');

    this.change({name: 'change', value: 'option3'});

  }
}
```

```
 <li>

  <ejs-radiobutton #radio label="Option 1" formControlName="option" name="option" (change)="onChanged($event)" [value]="'option1'"></ejs-radiobutton>

</li>

<li>

  <ejs-radiobutton (change)="onChanged($event)" label="Option 2" formControlName="option" name="option" [value]="'option2'"></ejs-radiobutton>

</li>

  <li>

  <ejs-radiobutton (change)="onChanged($event)" label="Option 3" formControlName="option" name="option" [value]="'option3'"></ejs-radiobutton>

</li>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).